# Function vs Method for map, filter, reduce

Tags: swift, function, methods, functional-programming

What are the advantages of one over the other?

Why languages like Swift and JavaScript decided to go with the method route?

I know I can do like Haskell and only have functions with operators to make it as readable as methods (when chaining), so why those languages went with methods?

EDIT: To clarify what I mean by "method route"

Collections in those languages have methods like `map`, `filter` and `reduce`, rather than having those as separate functions.

i.e., you'd use it like this:

`[1, 2, 3].map(...)` rather than `map(...)([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by method route. Don't Swift and JavaScript support function besides method?

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: The first example it is actually how it is done in swift

Comment: @LeoDabus exactly, that's what I meant when I said why methods instead of functions.

Comment: Your question it is opinion based

Comment: So there is no real difference between the 2? It's just a matter of taste?

Comment: I don't know. IMO "as I said" the only difference is the syntax. I prefer the traversing style over the function

Comment: JavaScript is multi-paradigm – it supports a variety of programming styles.

Comment: Yes it does, but by default there is no `map` function, only a `map` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the reason could be that languages like Swift and JavaScript are object-oriented languages. And object has methods, otherwise, there are no reasons to use objects at all. Languages like Haskell are functional programming languages, and they rely less on objects (some of them does not have objects at all, like clojure). So the question is why some of them are OO languages, and some are functional programming languages. I think because OO language and functional programming language both have their plus sides. Like in OO languages, you can achieve [good design principle](http://www.oodesign.com/design-principles.html). And functional programming language is very good for [multi-threading problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181284/functional-programming-and-multicore-architecture). So some choose this route and some choose the other.

But what's more important, languages are trying to be both object-oriented and functional. For example, both Swift and Javascript, they have closure, lambda, functions-as-first-class-object, immutability, etc. I think the border between oo language and functional language will become more and more blur. Even Java, which many people believe is one of the most object-oriented (Java has less functional language feature supported), has lambda now.

So it doesn't matter which route a language goes as it doesn't matter which language you uses (sometimes it does matter, especially one has higher performance demand).

I try to comment my thought here, but obviously, I exceed the maximum character limit. This won't be the only answer but hope it helps.